# Umbraco writing '/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=' to links

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have recently pushed an Umbraco site live, i.e moved the site to a live server from a development server. The database is in place and the site is up but none of the stylesheets or images are loading.

/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcss%2fmain.css%3fver%3d16&ver=16 404 (Not Found)

Umbraco seems to be adding '/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=' to links as the files are being requested.

I'm not sure what's going on but could this be some sort of permissions problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Also, I'm having trouble accessing /umbraco/, /umbraco/default.aspx works but there are no styles and the resulting admin panel has no fields. Whatever the problem is, it seems to be affecting everything.

FINAL EDIT

Solved, it was permissions. When I set it up I copied the permissions of a similar build (which I presumed was working). I'd noticed at that point that Plesk IIS User wasn't set to read, but I ignored that and carried on.

Should have trusted my own judgement, came back hours later, changed it to read and BOOM. Website go.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could be a permissions problem, try to set permission to read to the folder where the css files are located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is configured to use authentication, which means that some, or all, of the content on your site is not available for viewing to non=authenticated users. If the user is not authentictaed then Umbraco will redirect them to the login page (login.aspx).

There are various things you can do here. I had a question regarding authentication the other week which was discussed at the Our Umbraco forum:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/35957-Forms-Authentication-Loginaspx-page-has-not-styling-applied

An approach to deal with this, which is discussed in the forum question, was to use public access configuration in Umbraco. That is discussed here:

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-client/context-menus/public-access

This allows you to configure role-based (or single user based) permissions on your site, so you can control what user roles (or users) can see on the site.